# what's different about SAP HANA cloud?

Tags: hana

Kind of a noob question: SAP HANA Cloud calls itself an in-memory cloud platform. What does that mean exactly? Is this because they use their in-memory database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The SAP HANA Cloud Platform is the Platform as a Service offering from SAP based on the HANA In-Memory Technology. HANA has just been announced as the leader by Forester amongst In-Memory databases which really sets SAPs PaaS apart from the rest.

If you want to know more about HANA Cloud Platform, then please refer to this blog https://blogs.saphana.com/2014/03/05/saphcp-the-full-package/

If you want to try SAP HANA Cloud Platform, then please refer to https://account.hanatrial.ondemand.com/ - here you can create a free unlimited trial account.

If you would like to connect or learn more about SAP HANA or the HANA Cloud Platform, then please find me on twitter: @Arentoft

Answer (score 1):

Yes, HANA Cloud Platform uses the HANA in-memory database as the dbms, so your data is still being held, processed and analyzed from memory, and not disks.

[HANA Cloud Platform](http://hcp.sap.com/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

SAP HANA - Platform as a Service (PaaS),are used for applications and supporting cloud components to software. Basically, it is an in-memory database such as traditional databases like SQL, MSSQL,Sybase etc…

Benefits of [SAP HANA Cloud](http://www.kryptinc.com/krypt-cloud.php):-

- Achieve ROI for Global Trade Services
- Optimize resource planning
- Offers data security